# hdparm and disk read speed

Tags: c, bandwidth, fread

My `hdparm -t` buffered disk reads output is around 120 MB/sec. However, I was writing a little code that involves reading a big file (around 400MB), when I managed to read it all in about one second (`fread()` on `c`). Does the hdparm output not quite say what I understand? Why am I able to read so much faster?

I do very simple processing to the bytes I read, counting how many are the letter 'A'.

Comment: This isn't a "good question", i.e. it's borderline off-topic. You don't actually *show* any code, so it's hard to say much.

Comment: My guess is that your operating system has a cache and the large file happened to be in that cache.

Comment: @unwind: I don't really need to show any code, just the numbers I stated are the source of my question.
Can my OS have such a big cache? I also make sure I clear my disk cache before I run the program.

Answer (score 0):

hdparm is bypassing your OS's cache, but your test program is taking advantage of it.  Presuming you're running Linux, evict everything from the page cache with this command (source: http://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches):

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Then, run your test program.  It should be at or below the rate reported by hdparm.